# Function freezes website

Tags: php, debugging

Any idea why this php function is causing my website to freeze?

```
 function makeAgo($timestamp){

  $difference = time() - $timestamp;
  $periods = array("sec", "min", "hr", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
  $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
  for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++)
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    $difference = round($difference);
  if($difference != 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
    $text = "$difference $periods[$j] ago";
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: If `$difference = round($difference);` is supposed to be part of the loop body, you need some braces.

Comment: the way you've indented it, you clearly intend the `for()` and `if()` lines to apply to the two lines after them. Please note that this will not work unless you use `{}` braces around the blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your function is freezing if your timestamp difference goes less than zero value.
2. And one more thing you forgot to mention  length for decade or year. Otherwise your function working super...!!

Try Below..!!

```
 function makeAgo($timestamp){

$difference = time() - $timestamp;
if($difference < 0)
{
  $difference = 0;
}
$periods = array("sec", "min", "hr", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
$lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10","10");
for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++)
  $difference /= $lengths[$j];
  $difference = round($difference);
if($difference != 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
  $text = "$difference $periods[$j] ago";
  return $text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ver much. You are a scholar and a gentlemen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to change to this:

```
  for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++){
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    $difference = round($difference);
    if($difference != 1) $periods[$j].= "s";
      $text = "$difference $periods[$j] ago";
      return $text;
  }
```

Because if you use a loop without braces, only the first next statement is executed continously in the loop, but not any other statements.